# Receive messages from the Telegram channel

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm trying to get messages from the Telegram channel using the Telethon library.Every week messages are published by type:

- 1 message contains Surname
- 2 message for this surname

I need to get a message with the last name and the following message and ignore all other messages for other names.

I get the first message with the last name:

```
client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)

channel = 'MyChannel'

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'Surname' in event.raw_text:
        messageId = event.message.id +1
        await print(client.iter_messages(channel,offset_id=messageId)
```

I receive a message:

```
 <async_generator._impl.AsyncGenerator object at 0xfb8624c49>
```

Can you please tell me how to get the message I need in a readable form?

Answer (score 0):

> I receive a message: `<async_generator._impl.AsyncGenerator object at 0xfb8624c49>`

That is just the async generator object. To retrieve messages out of it, you need to *iterate* over it:

```
async for msg in client.iter_messages(channel,offset_id=messageId):
   print(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, please tell me how you can select messages by the list of last names, tried using While <len (list), does not work, how it is possible to organize in asynс?

Comment: @Vasai I'm not sure what you mean by "select messages by the list of last names". Do you want to create a list of messages by some criterion? Or sort them? Or do you want to create a list of names from the given messages?